# Potential energy for different states

Tags: thermodynamics, potential-energy, states-of-matter

While studying thermal physics at school, I have been taught that solids simply have more potential energy than the liquids and gases. Note that it was said that this potential energy is due to the intermolecular bonds between the atoms. However, my intuition makes me doubt this, why would there be more potential energy in a solid??? Lets see: the internal energy is the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of a body. Well liquids and gases have more kinetic - pretty clear. As for, our original point, the potential: well, if the body has potential to do work, via lets say, chemical reactions, then its solid form will have a higher activation energy, as the intermolecular bonds have to be broken first - so the energy then released from combustion or what not, is less than that of its gaseous equivalent! Then how is it, that solids are somehow said to have more "potential" energy than the more energetic states. I, upon questioning this, have been told that this is due to the forces of the molecular bonds, but really I think, these forces signalize a lack of potential energy!

Comment: This question is lacking information. What material are we talking about, under what conditions.

Comment: The energy released by chemical reaction is not directly related to the state (solid or liquid) but to the chemistry of the material. The energy related to state change is the energy transfered or released during a phase transition and not during a chemical reaction. Just making a general statement like this, without specifying how the PE is defined is quite meaningless. Gasoline releases higher energy than wood when burned (per unit mass) but this does not mean that liquids have more PE than solids.

Answer (score 1):

**Combustion is a chemical reaction** where the molecules rearrange themselves and is VERY VERY different from change of phase. The energy stored in the solid phase is not necessarily more than that stored in the liquid phase. For example, it takes more energy to convert water into stream ($2260 KJ/kg$) than ice into water ($334 KJ/Kg$).

Comment: Yes, that is clear to me, but then if you combust 1 mole of a solid or 1 mole of its gaseous equivalent, I believe the heat released to the environment for the solid is going to be less as energy will be used up to break the intermolecular bonds. Hence, a solid has less potential energy than a liquid or gas, in all regards.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about thermal physics, it's probably worth talking about this purely in a thermal context.

What does it mean for something to have a high amount of energy? It means that we can do a lot of work with it. So let's say we have some sort of machine that uses something to do work as efficiently as possible. Since we're talking about solids and liquids and gases in the abstract, we can assume that we're not extracting any kinetic or potential energy (since that's dependent on the exact context of the solid). Our machine, then, is a heat engine. We do work by pulling heat from a hot object and dumping it into a cold object. This means, then, that we can extract more heat from a hotter object, so hotter objects have more energy. Which is (generally) hotter: a solid or a gas?

In short, your teacher is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In solids and liquids, there are electrical forces between the molecules.

When we apply heat to a solid or liquid, we are doing work since we are separating molecules and getting rid of these electrical forces.

Think of it this way: imagine two atoms bonding because they are attracted to each other, it is like a positive and a negative charge attracting. So, to separate these attracted charges, work must be done, which is gone into increasing the potential energy.

Check out the left-most picture of the one below:

[image: the source of the image: http://guweb2.gonzaga.edu/faculty/cronk/CHEM101pub/energy.html]

Gases have zero potential energy (or close enough for real gases and zero for ideal gases). That means, that solids and liquids have negative potential energy.

So, as heat is applied to a solid or liquid, potential energy increases, so the value of potential energy becomes less negative and gets closer to zero.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Your image links is not accessible for me. Could you please upload the image using the built-in SE tool? Thanks! (You can [edit] your answer)

Answer (score -2):

Gas has highest potential energy than liquid and solid because potential energy of any matter depends upon inter molecular space and gases have highest inter molecular space.

Answer (score -5):

Sounds like some of you are smarter than me about some things.

But here is a revelation no one has mentioned. And why I'm more insightful than all of you. Matter itself is a phase of energy. Matter is a state of energy.
Everyone knows that an atom "contains" energy but a Unified Theory marries energy and mass.  In essence... matter is the fat of energy.
So then, there is more energy in a solid than a gas because it is a more dense phase... not of "matter" but of energy.  A relatively compensative amount of energy would need to be added to it just to overcome the intermolecular attractive forces to release the stored energy.

Speaking in a thermal sense, we find that in a glass of water full of ice that the water is 32° and the ice is also 32°.  That is possible because of something called latent energy which is the amount of energy added/subtracted to a substance WITHOUT a change in temperature and before reaching the next state of matter. It's as if the molecule spins up like Wonder Woman before changing state.
This is not a theory but an obvious observation.